# Application of MVT to prove inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have been asked the following question and have an answer of sorts;

Suppose that $f(0)=0$ and that $f'(x)$ is increasing for all $x \ge 0$. By applying the mean-value theorem to the points 0 and x, show that $$f(x) \le xf'(x)$$ for $x\ge 0$.

My initial answer is as follows;

Since $f'(x)$ is increasing we know that $f''(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \ge 0$. So considering a function $ g(x) = f(x) - xf'(x)$, and taking the derivative;

$$ g'(x) = f'(x) - (xf''(x) + f'(x)) \Leftrightarrow g'(x) = -xf''(x)$$

We then see that $g'(x) \le 0$ for all $x \ge 0$ and so $g$ is a decreasing function, and note that $g(0) = 0$. Hence $g(x) \le 0 \Leftrightarrow f(x) \le xf'(x)$ for all $x \ge 0$.

My concern is that I haven't used the mean-value theorem as requested but I'm not sure. Any help would be much appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Your solution is perfect. Instead of differentiating one more time, one could also use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look shortly at applying the mean value theorem instead of the differiation.

Comment: @berci OPs solution is not perfect, since it assumes that $f$ is twice differentiable - however, none of the assumptions suggest that this should hold.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, definitely not a rigorous proof then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the MVT, we note that MVT says that:

$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = f'(\xi) $ for some $\xi\in[0,x]$

but since $f(0) = 0$ that just gives

$f(x) = xf'(\xi)$

Hence by the increasing nature of $f'$ the result follows.

Having said that, your solution also appears to be perfectly valid.

Comment: Just like that! Many many thanks. And also thank you on verifying that my answer also appears to be valid.